# Find specific value from text file using python

Tags: python, text

I am learning python, and I don't know how to get a specific value from a text file.

Here is an example of the text file.

```
a1: 1   a2:     2   a3:     3   a4:     4  
a5: 5   a6:     6   a7:     7   a8:     8
```

I am trying to print out the value (1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8) in a different text file.

Comment: You can use `re` to find intergers from the given string. Look into `re.findall` and to match integers use `\d+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Import regex library
import re

# Open the file and read the text
with open('file1.txt') as file:
    text = file.read()

# Get list of integers in the file. \d matches digits in regex.
numbers = re.findall('a\d:\s*(\d)', text)

# Create a second file and write the numbers to it
with open('file2.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(' '.join(numbers))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
file = open('samp.txt')
file = file.readlines()

numbers_array = []
for line in lines:
    parts = line.strip('\n').split(' ')
    numbers = [i for i in parts if i.isnumeric()]
    numbers_array.extend(numbers)

with open('out.txt','a') as out:
    out.write(' '.join(numbers_array))
```